# Function Overloading failed

Tags: c++, sfinae, overload-resolution

When comparing two methods, if one method has a better match than the other solely based on the method's signature. And that better match ,method fails after deduction, why does the compiler directly report an error? And it seems not comply with the SFINAE.

```
#include <iostream>

class B {};

template <typename T>
void func(const T& t) {
    t.doSomething();
    std::cout << "func(T) - T does not have a member function 'doSomething()'" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void func(T&& t)  {
    std::cout << "func(T) - T has a member function 'doSomething()'" << std::endl;
}



int main() {
    const B b{};
    func(b);  

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler shows error: ‘const class B’ has no member named ‘doSomething’ for the code

Comment: Why did you expect the rvalue overload to be chosen when you don't pass an rvalue? This is also not related to SFINAE as SFINAE does not examine a function's body, only its (template) signature

Comment: The compilation error comes from the body of the function, so why do you think it should affect overload resolution / SFINAE ?

Comment: If you look at the full error message, you will see that the _instantiation_ of `func` is what triggers the error, and, as others have pointed out, that is the first overload.  Also, I don't know why you're talking about SFINAE as you're not using it.

Comment: @UnholySheep T&& can be passed a right value, and in that case T&& will be deduced as T&&& and equal to T&.

Comment: @PaulSanders Becuase I thought SFINAE can be used for function implementation. As the other answers have pointed out, I am totally wrong.

Comment: @TimH I really don't understand what you are trying to say there. `const B b{};` is not an rvalue and cannot be deduced to one in the function call `func(b);` - calling the rvalue overload would be e.g.: `func(B{});` (as unnamed temporary objects are "pure" rvalues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the function has no impact on SFINAE nor on overload resolution.

Overload resolution:

`func(b);`  will always call `func<B>(const B&)` because its the better match. For details see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution.

SFINAE:

There is no SFINAE in your code. There is return-type based SFINAE, parameter type based SFINAE, and maybe more, but no SFINAE based on a function templates implementation.

Calling the function:

Once overload resolution decided what function is called calling `t.doSomething();` is a hard error because `B` has no such method.

Comment: Aha thanks a lot. I thought SFINAE can be based on function templates implementation